# How to make Camel AWSSQS Consumer component synchronous

Tags: apache-camel, amazon-sqs

I am using 2.17.6 version of camel AWSSQS component ( consumer) to consume messages from a FIFO queue.

When the exchange processing takes longer than visibility timeout, camel is spinning up a new thread with the same message ( but a new exchange). This is happening because I am using long polling, and looks like this component is built to have asynchronous behavior by default.

In my case, I want to move on to the next message only when the current message gets deleted after processing. ( as my requirement is FIFO)

If I increase the visibility timeout to a high value(ex: 15 mins), that solves the issue. but I do have cases where I will go for infinite retry, and in those cases I don't want to cross the set high Visibility timeout and have multiple threads starting thus changing the order of execution.

Please suggest, if there is a way not to receive the next message in the queue until I am done processing the current one.

Thanks,
Sowjanya.

Comment: I had an interesting observation that I don't this issue if I opt for specifying visibility timeout in the AWSSQS component configuration. Even if I specify the visibilitytimeout to 10 secs ( less than default) I don't see that came route starting a new thread. If I don't specify the visibilitytimeout option, I see this issue. With that I have a workaround for now. This may be a defect with camel code. I tried but didn't have a success opening up a bug with camel. If anyone from camel group watch this thread, please do open up a defect if you think this is a valid issue.

Comment: Where did you open a bug for Sowjanya?

Comment: I figured out that Camel Nabble forums are now read-only. I was asked to use users@ mailing list to post questions/issues. But I never got a response on that mailing list. Hence, I started using stackoverflow. I have no clue where to open bugs.

Comment: you can raise a JIRA here, if you think this is a bug. https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/CAMEL